# exract number and float from string

Tags: python, regex, numpy, pycharm, python-re

```py
data =

{'s': 'ok',
 't': [1587486600, 1587490200, 1587493800, 1587497400],
 'c': [6832.0, 6905.99, 6900.0, 6880.0],
 'o': [6831.0, 6849.0, 6906.0, 6900.0],
 'h': [6849.0, 6916.0, 6906.0, 6900.0]}

output like this  =

[[[1587486600, 1587490200, 1587493800, 1587497400], [6832.0, 6905.99, 6900.0, 6880.0]],
 [[6831.0, 6849.0, 6906.0], [6849.0, 6916.0, 6906.0, 6900.0]]]
```

Comment: This is a `dict`, not a string.  Please consult a tutorial on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an array, it is an object:

```
Object.values(string).filter(item => typeof item === Array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a dictionary:

```
In [314]: dd ={'s': 'ok', 't': [1587486600, 1587490200, 1587493800, 1587497400], 'c': [6832.0, 6905.99,
     ...:  6900.0, 6880.0], 'o': [6831.0, 6849.0, 6906.0, 6900.0], 'h': [6849.0, 6916.0, 6906.0, 6900.0
     ...: ]}                                                                                           
In [315]: dd                                                                                           
Out[315]: 
{'s': 'ok',
 't': [1587486600, 1587490200, 1587493800, 1587497400],
 'c': [6832.0, 6905.99, 6900.0, 6880.0],
 'o': [6831.0, 6849.0, 6906.0, 6900.0],
 'h': [6849.0, 6916.0, 6906.0, 6900.0]}
```

You can get a list of the array values:

```
In [316]: list(dd.values())                                                                            
Out[316]: 
['ok',
 [1587486600, 1587490200, 1587493800, 1587497400],
 [6832.0, 6905.99, 6900.0, 6880.0],
 [6831.0, 6849.0, 6906.0, 6900.0],
 [6849.0, 6916.0, 6906.0, 6900.0]]
```

You can then use standard list indexing and methods to select a subset and/or regroup them.

Or you could select items from the dictionary with the usual dictionary indexing.

For example, you appear to want two sublists of lists:

```
In [317]: [[dd[key] for key in ['t','c']], [dd[key] for key in ['o','h']]]                             
Out[317]: 
[[[1587486600, 1587490200, 1587493800, 1587497400],
  [6832.0, 6905.99, 6900.0, 6880.0]],
 [[6831.0, 6849.0, 6906.0, 6900.0], [6849.0, 6916.0, 6906.0, 6900.0]]]
```